# Java generics interface implementation

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface as follows,

```
public interface MethodExecutor {
    <T> List<T> execute(List<?> facts, Class<T> type) throws Exception;
}
```

Also, I have a generic implementation like below,

```
public class DefaultMetodExecutor implements MethodExecutor {

   public <T> List<T> execute(List<?> facts, Class<T> type) throws Exception
   {
     List<T> result = null;

      //some implementation

      return result;
  }
}
```

Upto this there is no compilation issues,

But a specific implementation of this interface fails to compile, The one which shown below.

```
public class SpecificMetodExecutor implements MethodExecutor {

   public <Model1> List<Model1> execute(List<Model2> facts, Class<Model1> type) throws Exception
   {
     List<Model1> result = null;

     //some implementation specific to Model1 and Model2

      return result;
  } 
}
```

How can I implement this interface for some of the defined objects? Do I need to go for class level generics?

Comment: For long snippets of code, please use the code button or indent 4 spaces.  the tick mark is only used for code within text.

Comment: What exactly is the error of the compiler?

Answer (score 10):

You need to make `T` a class type parameter, not a method type parameter.  You can't override a generic method with a non-generic method.

```
public interface MethodExecutor<T> {
    List<T> execute(List<?> facts, Class<T> type) throws Exception;
}

public class DefaultMethodExecutor implements MethodExecutor<Model1> {
    public List<Model1> execute(List<?> facts, Class<Model1> type) throws Exception
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

If the element type of `facts` should be configurable for a specific implementation, you need to make that a parameter too.

```
public interface MethodExecutor<T, F> {
    List<T> execute(List<? extends F> facts, Class<T> type) throws Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to move your generic parameter types from method declaration to interface declaration, so you can parametrize specific implementations:

```
public interface MethodExecutor<T> {
    List<T> execute(List<?> facts, Class<T> type) throws Exception;
}

public class SpecificMetodExecutor implements MethodExecutor<Model1> {
    public List<Model1> execute(List<Model2> facts, Class<Model1> type) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```